# How can I download an Email using the Gmail api with Go

Tags: api, go, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

Trying to use the Go library of the Gmail API (v1) to get the raw content of a email and parse it as a byte slice {[]byte} so I can save it as an email. Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the package (https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/gmail/v1#Message) it states:

```
// Raw: The entire email message in an RFC 2822 formatted and base64url
// encoded string. Returned in `messages.get` and `drafts.get` responses
// when the `format=RAW` parameter is supplied.
```

Get the email using the rfc822msgId. This can be grabbed from the header.

```
gmailMessageResposne, _ := gmail.Service.Users.Messages.Get("user@email.com", "rfc822msgid").Format("RAW").Do()
```

Once you have the *gmail.Message object you can decode the raw string via

```
decodedData, _ := base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString(gmailMessageResposne.Raw)
```

Then

```
base64.URLEncoding(decodedData, decodedData)
```

Finally

```
ioutile.WriteFile("message.eml", decodedData, os.ModePerm)
```

This worked for me!